# Save a list in excel format in local Drive for Console Application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, console, export-to-excel

I have a List.
I want to Save the list in excel format (.xls) and save it to local drive in a console application ?

Its a Console Application ..I want to save it in a location

Comment: Linq to Excel is for querying Excel spreadsheets. Have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151005/create-excel-xls-and-xlsx-file-from-c-sharp about creating spreadsheets.

Comment: @Magnus My Bad. Actually i want to Export a list in my local drive (Not flush) ..As i am doing it in a console application .(I am modifying the question)

Answer (score 0):

1. First I have Converted the list in a DataTable.
2. List item Create Excel File from Datatable.
3. Save the Excel in a location in local Drive.

Code Snippets

```
DataTable boundTable = Utils.ConvertToDataTable(MyList);
/// <summary>
        /// Convert list to datatable
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="data"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static DataTable ConvertToDataTable(IList<MyEntity> data)
        {
            PropertyDescriptorCollection properties =
               TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(BDWData));
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
                table.Columns.Add(prop.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) ?? prop.PropertyType);
            foreach (BDWData item in data)
            {
                DataRow row = table.NewRow();
                foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
                    row[prop.Name] = prop.GetValue(item) ?? DBNull.Value;
                table.Rows.Add(row);
            }
            return table;

        }

CreateXLSFile(boundTable, FileName);


/// Create and Save Excel File from Datatable
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="dt"></param>
        /// <param name="strFileName"></param>
        public void CreateXLSFile(DataTable dt, string strFileName)
        {

            #region Export List to XLS

            string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyyyyHHmmssfff");
            string path = strFileName + "_" + date + ".xls";
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                // Create a file to write to.
                Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(ArchiveReportRoot);// Changed the default location of the storage of the file.
                StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path); //Append the file name with the file path.
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.AppendLine("<TABLE Border=1 ID=\"TableH2\">");
                sb.AppendLine("<TR>");
                sb.Append("<TD colspan=\"" + dt.Columns.Count + "\" style=\"background-color:#88b2fe\" align=\"center\">"
                                                            + "<b> " + strFileName
                                                            + "</b>" + "</TD>");
                sb.AppendLine("</TR>");
                sb.AppendLine("<TR>");
                for (int count = 0; count < dt.Columns.Count; count++)
                {
                    sb.AppendLine("<TD style=\"background-color:#88b2fe\"><b>" +
                        dt.Columns[count].ColumnName + "</b></TD>");
                }
                sb.AppendLine("</TR>");
                for (int count = 0; count < dt.Rows.Count; count++)
                {
                    sb.AppendLine("<TR>");
                    DataRow dr = dt.Rows[count];
                    for (int cellCount = 0; cellCount < dt.Columns.Count; cellCount++)
                    {
                        sb.AppendLine("<TD style=\"mso-number-format:'\\@';\">" + dr[cellCount] + "</TD>");
                    }
                    sb.AppendLine("</TR>");
                }
                sb.AppendLine("<TR>");
                for (int count = 0; count < dt.Columns.Count; count++)
                {
                    sb.AppendLine("<TD style=\"background-color:#88b2fe\"><b>" + "</b></TD>");
                }

                sb.AppendLine("</TR>");
                sb.AppendLine("</TABLE>");
                sw.Write(sb.ToString());
                sw.Write("\n");
                sw.Close();
            }

            else
            {
                #region Logging to the console and text file

                //***** Logging - START *****
                sb.Length = 0;
                sb.Append(Utils.CurrentDateTime);
                sb.Append("No BDW Records found on  " + Utils.CurrentDate);
                if (Utils.IsLoggingEnabled)
                {
                    Utils.LogException(sb.ToString(), LogListener.FireBackendListener);
                }
                Utils.WriteToConsole(sb.ToString());

                //***** Logging - END *****
                #endregion Logging to the console and text file
            }

            #endregion

        }
```

Please suggest me if you have some better option ..but above code works for me .